# UICollectionView - items not ordered as they should

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using UICollectionview to show 4 cells on each side (paginated). The Collectionview can be scrolled from left to right, snapping itself to always show the next or previous 4 cells. 
The problem is, the cells are ordered like this:

13
24

and I would like to have them show like this:
12
34

I'm using a flow layout. Is there any easy way of setting this? I would love to avoid sorting my datasource array to fit my expectations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is the standard layout for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` when scrolling horizontally. It doesn't make sense to have it lay out the other way. If you would like it that way you can subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and implement your own layout logic.